# Rails4 Access controller_name from model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have user role based access control. User has many roles. 
Each role has access to some controllers, actions and scopes.

I have method can_control?(controller) in User model which check if user have access to specific controller. I have similar method to actions.

Then in view or controller I can make simple logic to hide some information or permit access using:

```
current_user.can_control?(controller_name)
```

I wonder if it possible to create method in User model which automatically takes controller_name. I tried to define method in model.

```
def can_control?
    self.permitted_cotrollers.include?(controller_name)
end
```

But it gives me an error:

```
undefined local variable or method `controller_name' for #<User:0x007f00e8ceb928>
```

I understand error, but can find solution or if it possible to have one.

Comment: I think you still need to pass the controller name as parameters since can_control? is an instance method and you need to check the ability of the user to access certain controller. Controller_name also seems to change everytime you are loading different views. For easy implementation, you can try to use : https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

Comment: I'm afraid you have right. In this example it is pretty easy, but I need to have more complicated methods where I need to use this method and passing it in every method is not as DRY as I would like.

Comment: But I think if you just want to control access to your views and controller, you can actually try `cancancan` gem. I have tried it so many times and proven effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best solution I can think of : You can access the current controller name in `params[:controller]` from any controller method.

In User model :

```
def can_control?(params)
  self.permitted_controllers.include?(params[:controller])
end
```

In any controller :

```
current_user.can_control?(params)
```

Comment: Thanks, I implemented this and works well. That simplify my application.

Comment: You're welcome. I also hope that your `permitted_controllers` list is something you can set for groups of users, and not only for users. Otherwise, you may struggle to maintain the system one day.

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you can get the standard associated controller name by using :

```
"#{self.class.to_s}Controller"
```

- self refers to your model
- .class gets its class
- .to_s converts its class to a string containing its class name

If you need it written in snake_case instead of CamelCase, use this :

```
"#{self.class.to_s.tableize}_controller"
```

- .tableize converts the CamelCase name of your model into the snake_case name used in your controller

Comment: self.class in this case always return UserController. I wanted to share this between different controllers. So for example in PostController or Post view I could white:
`if can_control?` instead of `if can_control?(controller_name)`.

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't understand your actual need before. I'm gonna write another answer.